# Can't use su command to interactively login as another user

Tags: 20.04, login, password, su

I am currently using ubuntu 20.04 machine.
I created a user with password using the `useradd` command.
I need to change the `PATH` variable of that user. So i used `su - <username>` to interactivelly login to the user's shell. When it asked for the password, I provided the password of the user. But I am getting the below error.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-49-109:~$ su - harry
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

Does anyone know how can I fix this and how I acn change the `PATH` variable of the user

Comment: `su` is old, inflexible, and has been superseded by `sudo`. With `sudo`, what you want to do is trivial. Also `adduser` supersedes `useradd`. Read `man sudo sudoers adduser`.

Comment: Did you set the user's password after account creation (using `passwd` or `chpasswd` for example), or did you set it using the `-p` option of `useradd`? If the latter, did you remember to hash the password first (using something like `openssl passwd -stdin -6 <<< 'thepassword'`)?

Comment: Are you able to login normally as that user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I created a user with password using the `useradd` command.

Ok, I will take your word for that ... i.e. you attempted to create a new user with a password using **only** `useradd` ... Trying to imagine how you attempted that ... Probably using the `-p, --password` option and provided PASSWORD as plain text like so:

```
$ sudo useradd -p PASSWORD harry
```

Well, that is not going to work as the password provided should be an *encrypted password* as stated in [`man useradd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/useradd.8.html#options):

> ```
>  -p, --password PASSWORD
>
> The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).
> The default is to disable the password.
>
> Note: This option is not recommended because the password
> (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.
>
> You should make sure the password respects the system's password policy.
> ```

Therefore, the password you type(*which will be hashed/encrypted before comparing to the stored user's password "hash"*) is not actually the password stored on/expected by the system and the error `su: Authentication failure` is actually what it it means as the password cannot be authenticated/matched this way ... `su - harry` should work fine if you change the password using `sudo passwd harry` then try `su - harry` afterwords.

Furthermore, as also stated in the `man useradd` excerpt above, this is not the recommended way of setting a password for the user.

The recommended way is to use [`passwd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/passwd.1.html) after creating the user to set a password like so:

```
sudo passwd harry
```

This is the method used by [`adduser`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/adduser.8.html) ... Which is a front-end user friendly Perl script to `useradd` that you can inspect with:

```
cat /usr/sbin/adduser
```

to find out that it does that by calling the `passwd` system executable in this code excerpt:

> ```
> .
> .
> .
>     if ($ask_passwd) {
>     for (;;) {
>        my $passwd = &which('passwd');
>     # do _not_ use systemcall() here, since systemcall() dies on
>     # non-zero exit code and we need to do special handling here!
>       system($passwd, $new_name);
>     my $ok = $?>>8;
>     if ($ok != 0) {
> .
> .
> .
> ```

**Aftermath**:

After using `useradd`(*without using and providing valid/proper arguments to the `-d`, `-m` and `-s` options*) to create your new user i.e. **NOT** like so:

```
sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/harry -m harry
```

Then, you probably most likely will end up with no home directory for the new user and with `dash`(*The default for `/bin/sh` as defined in `useradd -D`*) and not `bash` as your new user's default login shell ... Therefore, you might want to:

1. Create a home directory for the new user the right way like so:

   ```
   sudo mkhomedir_helper harry
   ```
2. Change the login shell for the new user to `bash` like so:

   ```
   sudo chsh -s /bin/bash harry
   ```

Next time you create a new user, use `adduser` instead as it is a user friendly command and will take care of all the above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Raffa. But it seems it opens an interactive non-login shell of the user. Eventhough I have added the -d (home directory) option with the useradd command, when i am trying to login using su - harry, it gave me the error, "su: warning: cannot change directory to /home/school/harry/: No such file or directory" and opens an intercative non -login shell. I actually wanted to open an interactive login shell of the user. Can you please guide me ?

Comment: @AlakanandaS `useradd` doesn’t create a home directory for the user among other things … You figured that out already … The other thing you need to know is the default shell might be `dash`(*/bin/sh*) and not `bash` so you might need to change your shell with `chsh` … `useradd -D` should print the default shell assigned by default … and `echo $0` should print your current shell.

Comment: I have changed the shell to /bin/bash and checked the /etc/passwd file. but i can see that the home directory is listed there (harry:x:1002:1003::/home/school/harry/:/bin/bash) . But why when i am trying to login, it is saying that the directory is not created?

Also Interestingly, I tried to create a different user using 'adduser' command, and tried to login using su - <username>, it works perfectly as expected. An interactive login shell is opened for the user. 

Can you tell me why this happens when I use the useradd command?

Comment: @AlakanandaS The `-d` option of `useradd` specify the home directory yes … But, doesn’t create it if it doesn’t exist “please see the manual page” … You will need to create it in the specified path :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following command:

```
sudo -i -u harry
```

If it asks for a password, type in your own password (not harry's). Because of this, it will allow you to log in to user accounts with **no** password set (such as `root` by default).

Parameters (from [`man sudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/sudo.8.html)):

> `-i` Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile` or `.login` will be read by the shell.
>
> `-u` Run the command as a user other than the default target user (usually `root`).